# Database error (caused by WooCommerce?) when trying to test WordPress site locally

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, xampp, localhost

I have a WordPress website hosted on GoDaddy and want to test it locally.

I exported the database to SQL format and downloaded it on my local machine. Then I installed XAMPP and changed the config file ports from 80 to 8080. Now I can open my localhost on `LOCALHOST:8080` instead of `LOCALHOST`.

After the port changes I created a new directory in XAMPP and inserted a HTML file to test on `LOCALHOST:8080`. It worked, so I was ready to transfer my WordPress files.

Firstly, I dragged and dropped all my WordPress files into the new folder I've created. Next I imported the database file into the MySQL.
Finally I tried to access the WordPress site on my local using `LOCALHOST:8080/wordpress/wp-admin`, but when the site page comes up I get an error message, saying that my password or username is incorrect ad to open the `wp-config` file and update the info.

I opened the `wp-config` and changed the `localhost` option to `localhost:8080`. Also changed the database username and password. I can connect to the database now, but I'm getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Error saving action: Error saving action: Database error. in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\migration\ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php:44 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\data-stores\ActionScheduler_HybridStore.php(242): ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator->save_action(Object(ActionScheduler_Action), NULL) #1 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\ActionScheduler_ActionFactory.php(177): ActionScheduler_HybridStore->save_action(Object(ActionScheduler_Action)) #2 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\ActionScheduler_ActionFactory.php(84): ActionScheduler_ActionFactory->store(Object(ActionScheduler_Action)) #3 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\functions.php(36): ActionScheduler_ActionFactory->single('action_schedule...', Array, 1630078934, 'action-schedule...') #4 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\migration\Scheduler.php(89): as_schedule_single_action(1630078934, 'action_schedule...', Array, 'action-schedule...') #5 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\migration\Controller.php(99): Action_Scheduler\Migration\Scheduler->schedule_migration() #6 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): Action_Scheduler\Migration\Controller->schedule_migration('') #7 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-settings.php(600): do_action('wp_loaded') #10 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-config.php(111): require_once('C:\\xampp\\apps\\w...') #11 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\\xampp\\apps\\w...') #12 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\\xampp\\apps\\w...') #13 C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\apps\\w...') #14 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\packages\action-scheduler\classes\migration\ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php on line 44
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is documented on Action Scheduler github page and related to an internal DB migration and missing table.

```
add_action( 'init', function() { delete_option( 'schema-ActionScheduler_StoreSchema' ); } );
```

You can but this snippet in your theme’s functions.php, visit the site, and delete it when the error has gone

Answer (score 0):

Note: I do not have enough reputation to comment, so someone else can comment and I can delete this answer.

It seems to me that the user used to access/connect the database server, now that it can connect, just needs to be **granted privileges** to read and write to the database and it's tables that you imported.

Read the GRANT General Overview section (or the whole page if you have the patience) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

and grant the same user you added in the  wp-config  file enough permissions to read and write to the database/tables in the database.

Be specific where you can, i.e choose the user if possible, the host if possible, the database if possible,  the tables if possible and the permission access (insert select, etc) if possible.
Remember though much of these can take wildcards: (i.e. ALL,  *, %)

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'%';
```

if you cant get specific enough, relax the GRANT using wildcards  until you see somethings working, then tighten them up again.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem can fix with check database table wpvl_actionscheduler_actions
action_id is not a AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: You should change the formatting of your answer